# Rails AJAX Search form reloading page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

New to AJAX and search. I feel like I'm an inch away on this one, but I'm not sure what to fix. Also, my controller looks really hacky to me right now.

At any rate, I'm trying to create a search that allows users to search through blog posts on my page using AJAX. Here are the (relevant parts of the) parts:

**posts_controller.rb**

```
def show
  @posts = Post.all.reverse
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
  @link_num = 10

  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { redirect_to @post }
  end
end

def search
  @link_num = 10
  @posts = Post.all.reverse
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])

  #The including function returns the search results
  @search = Post.first.including(params[:term])
  render 'show'
end
```

What strikes me as "hacky" here is that I repeat all the variable assignments (there are others I didn't show cause they're not relevant). Shouldn't an AJAX call ideally not have to redefine/reload all these variables? Also, I have to pass :id to my search action through a hidden field. This feels weird/wrong to me.

**show.html.erb**

```
<h1 class="squeeze">Recent Posts</h1>
  <%= form_tag("/search", method: "get", class: "search") do %>
        <%= text_field_tag(:term, '', placeholder: "Search posts:") %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag(:id, @post.id) %>
        <%= submit_tag("Search", class: "btn search_button", remote: true) %>
    <% end %>
  <% if !@search%>
    <ul>
        <% @posts.first(@link_num).each do |p| %>
            <li><a href=<%= p.id %> ><%= p.name %> <span class="manual_small">(<%= p.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %>)</span></a></li>
        <% end %>
        <% if @posts.length > @link_num %>
            <div class="link_disclaimer">
            <h4>---</h4>
            <h5><%= "Only showing #{@link_num} most recent posts." %></h5>
            <h5>Search to narrow results.</h5>
        </div>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% elsif @search.empty? %>
    <h3>Term not found!</h3>
  <% else %>
    <ul>
        <% @search.first(@link_num).each do |p| %>
            <li><a href=<%= p.id %> ><%= p.name %> <span class="manual_small">(<%= p.created_at.strftime("%b %d, %Y") %>)</span></a></li>
        <% end %>
        <% if @search.length > @link_num %>
            <div class="link_disclaimer">
                <h4>---</h4>
                <h5><%= "Only showing first #{@link_num} relevant hits." %></h5>
                <h5>Narrow search for more specific results.</h5>
            </div>
        <% end %>
    </ul>
  <% end %>
```

**routes.rb**

```
match '/search', to: 'posts#search'
```

Currently, the search itself works fine, with three major problems:

1. The aforementioned messiness of my Controller.
2. The fact that the whole page reloads. Isn't that the opposite of what AJAX is supposed to do? How can I get it to reload just the list of links?
3. The URL. It's super messy (i.e "/search?utf8=✓&term=limits&id=11&commit=Search"). I'd ideally have it remain untouched by the search, but if that's not possible, maybe just something like "/search?=". How's that done?

Comment: But I can't see any Ajax logic here in you code?

Comment: Just the remote:true in the submit tag. I used to have it on the form_tag, but I moved it. I thought that was all I needed with Rails. I've never used AJAX with Rails or otherwise, so I'm not sure where the AJAX logic would go.

Comment: Ajax needs both Javascript and server side code to implement. I assume what you need is something like Google search, after hitting some characters the whole search results changed. Is that correct?

Comment: Well, yeah. Not google insta-search (though that'd be nice, I guess). I'm currently doing it so that the whole search would rerun whenever the user presses submit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the comment here is basic logic to make the function work(Sorry for no real code as that is too time consuming)

1. In controller you make a method say "search". The method need an argument which is the phrase to search. It gets the result from db and respond to JSON only with the result.
2. In template you have a search form.
3. In JS, you listen the event of user clicking the submit button, catch the characters they write, and handle it to ajax function.
4. Write Ajax code, preferred using jQuery's ajax(). Basically use ajax() to send the typed characters to controller method in #1 as argument. Then ajax() will get the response(the search result) from server.
5. Update the result in DOM. You can either add a new div to show search result, or replace current main content div to show result.